# What will the _escaped_fragment_ request look like for this AJAX URL?

Tags: ajax, seo, url-encoding, fragment-identifier

Say I have an AJAX application with this URL:  `http://www.foo.com/bar#!a=1&b=2&c=3`

What will the [crawable AJAX](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/) request from GoogleBot look like?

I assumed this:

**A)** `http://www.foo.com/bar?_escaped_fragment_=a%3D1%26b%3D2%26c%3D3`

But it looks like it's really this: (i.e. the `=`s are not url encoded)

**B)** `http://www.foo.com/bar?_escaped_fragment_=a=1%26b=2%26c=3`

Is it correct that **B)** is the actual request I'll receive?

On close examination of the [spec](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) it looks like **B)** is correct, but I still find it a bit surprising since many canned query string parsers will probably not give you the result you want with this input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this myself.

The correct answer seems be be neither A) or B) in the above question.  If the "clean" AJAX URL is `http://www.foo.com/bar#!a=1&b=2&c=3`, the "ugly" _escaped_fragment_ version is `http://www.foo.com/bar?_escaped_fragment_=a=1%26b=2%26c=3`.  So the `=` are not escaped, but the `&` are.  This is covered in the [spec](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html).